# Connecting different Simulink models on different computers

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I want to run different  models in different computers synchronously using real time Simulink. Is there any way that I can make a connection between two computers and transfer data in between them and run the simulations in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is to use the [UDP Send](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/udpsend.html) and [UDP Receive](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/udpreceive.html) blocks to transfer data between the two models. However, be aware that:

1. These blocks are part of the DSP System Toolbox (there are equivalent ones in the [Instrument Control Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udpsend.html), not sure what the difference is between the two)
2. Even with these blocks, it won't be "real-time". The only way to ensure hard real-time is to generate C code from a model and run it on a real-time platform. MATLAB/Simulink runs on non-real time O/S so can't be real-time. Having said that, if your model runs faster than real-time, you can slow it down to pseudo real-time. There are various utilities available to do that, see [Slowing Down Simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112913/slowing-down-simulink/28113238) for more details.

There are also TCP/IP [send](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpipsend.html) and [receive](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpipreceive.html) blocks in the Instrument Control Toolbox. These are more restrictive than their UDP counterparts, but ensure better integrity of the data transfer.

Comment: But it is possible to establish a connection between Matlab and XPCTarget like SpeedGoat.Why cannot I do it on a normal computer? Thank you

Comment: Because in the case of xPC Target, the target machine runs a real-time OS, where the C code generated from the Simulink model on the host runs (in real-time). The host-target communications are done via TCP/IP, and the exact mechanism of this is proprietary to MathWorks, but I imagine that it is similar to the TCP/IP communications with the Instrument Control Toolbox. The host machine basically tries to keep up with the real-time execution on the target machine, but there is some lag between the two.