# Videos in Simulink show too fast

Tags: performance, matlab, video, simulink, avi

when I run videos, for example this here from Simulink:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/tracking-cars-using-optical-flow.html

everything works fine, but all my videos in Simulink run too fast. About 5 times faster then normal. I use Win10 64bit, and also Matlab/Simulink for 64bit. The video files play with correct speed in Windows Media Player or all other Media Player.

Why are the videos play so fast in Simulink?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Simulink is a simulation framework, which returns the results as fast as possible. Unless you artificially slow it down, it will always run as fast as your PC allows. If you really want to slow it down choose one of the [options listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28113238/2732801), but this is typically not what you want to do. Instead I recommend to write the results back to an avi-file if you really need to analyse the results in detail.